# debug python multiprocess in a multithreaded environment

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pickle, deadlock

I am trying to use python multiprocessing in an existing service - the existing code starts up an http server, and thereafter, starts executing the code in a multi-threading env. Before the first thread (daemonic) begins, some API endpoints are defined. Whereas after it begins, 2 threads are spawned to run in the background, pushing data to destination, as and when necessary

**NOTE** that the python multiprocess starts "on the first thread"
The problem surfaces after a couple of hours, when curl requests to these endpoints begin to hang, although the program, both the multiprocess and the other worker threads run without any errors

a couple of points for the code below:

1. It is a requirement - that the startup sequence not be altered -
   hence I have to define multiprocessing on first thread, instead of main process
2. nomenclature used is indicative of purpose
3. target method of multiprocessing, will also require context object, as well as objects from other modules in the project, like: self.anotherprojectmodule_python
4. target method of multiprocessing has a while True loop, and "breaks" if
   an exception occurs, thereafter terminating multiprocessing in main
   code
5. ToCreateObjectof_AnotherModule includes I/O operation
6. I did already check for zombie processes using "ps aux", does not indicate cpu_time being overwhelmed no pickling errors are encountered
7. If the multiprocessing is initialized anywhere outside first thread, the endpoints return an error: connection refused

   8. I/O operations are API calls and no data is being written to disk; logs are being generated via logger

Please help!! 
Appreciate some explanation, I'm fairly new to python

```py
class MyService(ServerService):

    _th_event = threading.Event()

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.anotherprojectmodule_python = ToCreateObjectof_AnotherModule(context)

    def second_method(self):
        self._first_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._first_target, name="first", daemon=True) 
        define_api_endpoint_on_http_server("/endpoint/url1", self._target_f1)
        define_api_endpoint_on_http_server("/endpoint/url2", self._target_f2)
        define_api_endpoint_on_http_server("/endpoint/url3", self._target_f3)

    def lets_begin_thread(self):
        self._first_thread.start()

    def then_lets_begin_action(self):
        self._worker1_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._some_func, name="worker1", daemon=True) 
        self._worker2_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._func_with_i/o, name="worker2", daemon=True) 
        self._separate_worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._another_func_with_i/o, name="SeparateMemory", daemon=True)

        self._worker1_thread.start()
        self._worker2_thread.start()

        while not MyService.th_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(5)
            if not self._worker1_thread.is_alive():
                self._worker1_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._some_func, name="worker1", daemon=True)
                self._worker1_thread.start()
            if not self._worker2_thread.is_alive():
                self._worker2_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._func_with_i/o, name="worker2", daemon=True) 
                self._worker2_thread.start()
            if not self._separate_worker.is_alive():
                if self.anotherprojectmodule_python.CheckGet_value_from_worker2_target():
                    self._separate_worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._another_func_with_i/o, name="SeparateMemory", daemon=True)
                    self._separate_worker.start()

        log.debug("Exit..")
```

Adding 2 memory traceback using tracemalloc

`Top 10 lines |
'#1: /usr/lib/python3.5/linecache.py:137: 1711.0 KiB |    lines = fp.readlines() |`
#2: :476: 1234.3 KiB |
`#3: /url/to/py-pkg/uvloop/__init__.py:19: 506.8 KiB |    return Loop() |`
#4: /url/to/py-pkg/json/decoder.py:355: 227.1 KiB |    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) |
`#5: /url/to/py-pkg/idna/uts46data.py:8204: 154.5 KiB |    + _seg_78() |`
#6: /url/to/py-pkg/tracemalloc.py:65: 130.4 KiB |    return (self.size, self.count, self.traceback) |
`#7: /url/to/py-pkg/site-packages/pyformance/stats/samples.py:74: 64.4 KiB |    self.values[priority] = value |`
#8: /url/to/py-pkg/urllib/parse.py:535: 57.1 KiB |    for a in _hexdig for b in _hexdig} |
`#9: /url/to/py-pkg/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py:590: 24.1 KiB |    events = self._poll.poll(self.get_next_deadline()) |`
#10: /url/to/py-pkg/http/cookiejar.py:1224: 13.4 KiB |    yield from deepvalues(obj) |
`1828 other: 1146.3 KiB |`
Total allocated size: 5269.4 KiB |
`No changes for nodes or appstacks or packages. |`
Time Taken to complete register_members: 0.1754981119884178 |

`Top 10 lines |`
#1: /url/to/py-pkg/linecache.py:137: 1711.0 KiB |    lines = fp.readlines() |
`#2: <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:476: 1234.3 KiB |`
#3: /url/to/py-pkg/site-packages/uvloop/**init**.py:19: 506.8 KiB |    return Loop() |
`#4: /url/to/py-pkg/json/decoder.py:355: 228.5 KiB |    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) |`
#5: /url/to/py-pkg/idna/uts46data.py:8204: 154.5 KiB |    + _seg_78() |
`#6: /url/to/py-pkg/tracemalloc.py:65: 130.4 KiB |    return (self.size, self.count, self.traceback) |`
#7: /url/to/py-pkg/site-packages/pyformance/stats/samples.py:74: 64.4 KiB |    self.values[priority] = value |
`#8: /url/to/py-pkg/urllib/parse.py:535: 57.1 KiB |    for a in _hexdig for b in _hexdig} |`
#9: /url/to/py-pkg/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py:590: 24.1 KiB |
events = self._poll.poll(self.get_next_deadline()) |
`#10: /url/to/py-pkg/http/cookiejar.py:1224: 13.4 KiB |`
yield from deepvalues(obj) |
`1837 other: 1166.7 KiB |`
Total allocated size: 5291.3 KiB |

Coroutine traceback:
OrderedDict([('txt', ' 
cb=[run_until_complete..()]>'), ('type', ""), ('done', False), ('cancelled', False),

('stack', 
[OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object _bootstrap at 0x7f8246656420, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 868'), ('f_lineno', '882')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object _bootstrap_inner at 0x7f82466565d0, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 899'), ('f_lineno', '914')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object run at 0x7f8246656390, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 851'), ('f_lineno', '862')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object _start_services at 0x7f8240449a50, file "/url/to/parent_code_file.py.py", line 139'), ('f_lineno', '222')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object start at 0x7f8246064ae0, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 95'), ('f_lineno', '105')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object _Popen at 0x7f8246060780, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/context.py", line 210'), ('f_lineno', '212')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object _Popen at 0x7f8246060c90, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/context.py", line 264'), ('f_lineno', '267')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object **init** at 0x7f823fab4810, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 16'), ('f_lineno', '20')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object _launch at 0x7f821c2799c0, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 64'), ('f_lineno', '74')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object _bootstrap at 0x7f8245feb390, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 228'), ('f_lineno', '249')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object run at 0x7f8246064a50, file "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88'), ('f_lineno', '93')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object collect_api_telemetry at 0x7f8240461150, file "/url/to/code_file.py", line 35'), ('f_lineno', '108')]),

OrderedDict([('f_code', 'code object initiate_api_crawl at 0x7f8240330540, file "/url/to/code_file.py", line 257'), ('f_lineno', '278')])]), ('exception', None)])

Comment: I recommend you using DASK to multiprocessing, you have done all you have written. https://dask.org/

Comment: viewers, any idea why there isn't any response here, yet? Im a new contributor, please do excuse me for missing out any specific input, and please advise

Comment: Did you check for memory issues?

Comment: @Marc I am using memory trace using tracemalloc, coroutine traceback for the coroutines running and thread dump for the different threads - let me add those here to the question

Comment: @Marc please advise

Comment: Is this the situation when the program starts to hang?

Comment: its not the program that hangs; just the endpoints defined in method "second_method"; in other words, curl requests  to these endpoints don't fetch results/response or errors, just hung - these logs are from after the process hangs; the program hangs arbitrarily after 20min or even an hour;

Comment: @Marc, would you need any other traces of memory footprints?

Comment: No I can't really make sense of what is going on from them, sorry. Is there somewhere where they interact with the same non-multiprocessing safe object from multiple endpoints? Since it happens arbitrarily maybe that's when they are both waiting for something to happen

Comment: @Marc well, the multiprocess is initialized in fork mode, from what I read on documentation on multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html, "Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic" - do you think this could be the issue?

Comment: @Marc there is no interaction between main process and the multiprocess; from your  comment, can you please help explain - "same non-multiprocessing safe object from multiple endpoints"

Comment: You talk about IO, so are they maybe trying to open the same file at same time?

Comment: @Marc no files are being opened or accessed; is initiating a multiprocess inside a multithreading env. a good practice?

Comment: @Marc as for IO, the multiprocess is fetching response from a set of APIs asynchronously and posting to another single API - this is being done using an aiohttp session self-managed by a "with" clause, whereas please note that the http server being setup at the very beginning (start-up) of the service is also aiohttp